# ¿Como puedo saber cuando una cadena comienza y termina con la misma letra?

Tags: c

No se como hacer la comparacion de la primer letra con la ultima. El ejercicio es el siguiente:

Leer una cadena por teclado, visualizar si dicha cadena comienza y termina con la misma letra.

No se que hacer T.T

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char cadena [10];
    int largo,i,contador;

    printf ("Ingresar una palabra de maximo 10 caracteres: ");
    gets (cadena);

    largo=strlen(cadena);

    if (cadena[0]==cadena[largo]){
        printf("La primer y ultima palabra coinciden");
    }
    else{
        printf("La primer y ultima palabra no coinciden");
    }
    
    printf ("\n\n\n\n");
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código que has intentado

Comment: El error está en la comparación, debe de ser `if (cadena[0] == cadena[largo-1])`, porque así como la tienes estás comparando la letra de inicio con el caracter de fin de cadena `\0`

Comment: Como complemento al comentario de @OscarGG, ¿Cómo sabe una computadora dónde inicia y dónde termina una cadena de texto? Mediante el carácter nulo (**\0**), además observa que los índices de una cadena empiezan en 0, por lo que una palabra de 5 letras debe tener una longitud de 6 caracteres (incluyendo el carácter de término). Clase -> [C, l, a, s e, \0]. Donde la posición 5 es **\0** y la posición 4 sería la **e**, por eso es que debe ser `largo - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Puede que mi respuesta te ayude, o puede que no. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera (es un poco largo, eso sí):

```
    char x = '';

    while (cadena[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (i == (largo - 1))
        {
            x[0] = cadena[i];
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Te explico: básicamente, estás recorriendo la cadena de texto que tienes, y que cuando la cadena llegue a la máxima posición menos uno (ya que la última será `\0` siempre), pues almacena el valor en una variable. Luego, solo deberás comprobarlo con el `if - else` que tienes, y listo. Espero que te sirva, cualquier cosa puedes escribirme!